# autofac "Hello World" app in C# - initialization

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am looking for some help with a simple "Hello World" example of DI.  What I don't understand is how to initialize the classes "Foo" and "Bar" within a DI framework (autofac).

```
namespace AutofacTesting
{
    //these classes are intended to be used with autofac / DI
    public interface IFooBar
    {
        void Draw();
    }

    public class Bar : IFooBar
    {           
        public void Draw()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Drawing something in Bar");
        }
    }

    public class Foo : IFooBar
    {
        public void Draw()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Drawing somthing in Foo");
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IFooBar>();
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFooBar>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            var taskController = container.Resolve<IFooBar>();

            taskController.Draw();

            int a = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean you want to resolve a `Bar` or `Foo` class as the concrete implementation, not instantiate it. If so you could write:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<Bar>().Named<IFooBar>("Bar");
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().Named<IFooBar>("Foo");

var container = builder.Build();

var taskController = container.ResolveNamed<IFooBar>("Bar");

taskController.Draw();
```

I also realize this is a hello world application, but be careful not to fail into the [anti-pattern of using a service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) (i.e. using contain.Resolve all over the place). Instead, consider designs which will allow you to have all the registration and resolving happen in the same place, named a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx).

I mention this caution becuase having this level of ambiguity (i.e. multiple concreate types being registered for a given interface) can cause one to start using the service locator pattern. Instead, in more complex applications, consider refactoring your API to have less ambiguity upon resolving registered types.